# Split Data of 1 dataGridView into 2 using C#

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview

i am creating C# application in which i am loading data from database in winform dataGridView. i have timer of 10 seconds interval. i am refreshing gridView by timer. all i want is that when gridView loads data again it load new data into second grid. i want new rows in second grid.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**

i am trying this by calculating gridView rows and then count new rows in dataset that loads after refreshing the data. if there are some other rows in dataset, i want these rows in new grid.

please help me or suggest me how to apply loop

```
for (int i = gridRows; i < dataSetRows; i++)
 {
 drForSMS["USERID"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
 drForSMS["NAME"] = dataSetForDefautLoad.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think more clear way would be to clear all rows and then bind the grid to the newly (refreshed) dataset.

When you first open the application, bind the first grid to the `DataSet` and the second grid to `null`. Keep the first `dataset` into a `collection variable` locally.

On timer event load your dataset into some collection and do the binding.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();

            list1.Add(1);
            list1.Add(2);

            // Now this is your refresh which will load all data from first load, plus the refresh load
            List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
            list2 = list1;
            list2.Add(3);
            list2.Add(4);
            list2.Add(5);

            // Now you want the new values only in list2
            // Like we said, keep the original list1 in local variable so you can do this
            foreach (var l in list1)
            {
                if (list2.Contains(l))
                    list2.Remove(l);
            }
```

Then simply bind the second grid to `null`, then to `list2`.

2.
Another way to do this is:
You keep the count of the first query when you run the application. For example you got 5 records.
Then for the second grid you loop from 5 and above to load the second grid.

DataSet dsFirst = new DataSet();
        DataSet dsNew = new DataSet();

```
    var rows = dsFirst.Tables[0].Rows;

    var newRows = dsNew.Tables[0].Rows;

    // Choose your collection type here...
    var forBinding = new List<object>();

    for (int i = rows.Count - 1; i < newRows.Count; i++)
    {
        forBinding.Add(newRows[i]);
    }


    dataGrid.DataSource = forBinding;
```

3. An example with `DataSet`

   DataSet dsFirst = new DataSet();
           var initialCount = dsFirst.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

   ```
       DataSet dsRefreshed = new DataSet();

       for (int i = 0; i < initialCount; i++)
       {
           dsRefreshed.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(i);
       }

       dg.DataSource = dsRefreshed;
   ```

Just ask if you need to adjust this to your code.

Comment: new dataset will contain all previous data too. how i can i load them in seperate grid?

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, you want to load the first grid the first time you run the application, then on every refresh, you want to keep the first grid and populate the second one with the new data and on every 10 seconds the second grid will grow?

Comment: i am counting the records of first grid but i dont know how to load data from new dataset from counting like new data after 5 records

Comment: Ok, check the code sample for the second approach, it should help you.

Comment: could you please adjust sample code for adding data into datatable?like this one is for list type

Comment: Perhaps you should bind to List collection instead of the DataSet directly. That will allow the flexibility to "break" to sublist and bind the second grid. Otherwise to achieve this with dataset you will need to construct a dataset dynamically in the loop and bind the second grid to that (which is more complicated than what I have shown)

Comment: It is best practice to abstract the data access layer and work with business object rather than binding your dataGrid to dataSet directly. Having said that - if you still want to use the datasets directly you could use the dataSet.tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt[i] method inside a loop to clear the first loaded records and just show the new ones on the second grid.